# Spring Oauth2 client and user credentials combination

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing an app secured with Spring Oauth2, `password` flow.

But I'm still confused about difference between UserDetailService and ClientDetailsService flows in Spring.

As I understand from OAuth2 specification, client and user are different entities. **Client** has `clientId`, `clientSecret` and some `grants`, and **User** has `username`, `password` and also some `grants`.

Multiple users use the same client (mobile app or web browser in my case).

So I need to authenticate some user and provide it with an access token.

I have implemented both `UserDetailsService` and `ClientDetailsService` (with all needed infrastructure: AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter) and during authentication I see, that username from request is passed as `clientId` into clientDetailsService and 
 as `username` into userDetailsService.

But I thought it should be more complex process like for authentication request client should provide both client credentials and user credentials so then I can verify client (is it registered in my system) and its grants then verify user and its grants and then return an access token.

My questions:

1. Do I understand the process correctly?
2. Are client grants and user grants of the same meaning?
3. What classes should I customize to separate verification of client and user credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is stupid simple.

The client and the user are really different entities
To obtain access token you need to complete basic authentication with `Base64 encoded client credentials` in header and `username/password of the user in params`.

Header pseudocode:

`Basic Base64("client_id:client_secret")`

Params:

`username=username, password=password, grant_type=password`

This will return you access_token, refresh_token and some extra info.